# HOW TO fetch nodes with multiple edge type as starting point

Tags: memgraphdb, opencypher

Below is my dataset:

```
MERGE (pNode:product_sku {model_id: 1})
MERGE (f1:formula {model_id: 1})
MERGE (f2:formula {model_id: 2})
MERGE (f3:formula {model_id: 3})
MERGE (f4:formula {model_id: 4})
MERGE (f5:formula {model_id: 5})

MERGE (pNode)-[:has]->(f1)
MERGE (pNode)-[:influences]->(f2)
MERGE (pNode)-[:influences {simulation_id: 1}]->(f3)
MERGE (f1)-[:influences]->(f4)
MERGE (f4)-[:influences]->(f5)
```

I want to be able to fetch f4, f5, and f2 from f1 node.

this is my query so far:

```
MATCH (node1:formula {model_id: 1})-[edge1:influences* (r, n | r.simulation_id IS NULL)]->(n:formula) RETURN DISTINCT n
```

with my query above i am able to fetch `f4` and `f5` but i want to fetch `f2` also from `pNode`